# Finding item in list is slow

Tags: c#, list

I have a list:

```
List<symbol> table = new List<symbol>();
```

My class symbol have this structure:

```
public class symbol
{
  public byte c;
  public ulong low;
  public ulong high;
  public ulong freq;
}
```

When I searching in loop right symbol in list, this take too much time:
Just for example:

```
sim = table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.c == b); //26 sec
sim = table.Where(i => i.c== b).FirstOrDefault(); //20 sec
sim = table.Find(x => x.c == b); //10 sec
sim = table[1]; //3 sec
```

Here is time from my all program, where I change only this line.
My list size is about 2-256 but I searching about 100mil.
I want searching must quicker then 10 sec in my example.
How can I search more quickly in `list<>`? Or exist quick good solution without list with same result?

Comment: Can you provide more details on the size of the list? and also what does `c` represent?. These performances are really strange.. Can you also show how you measured it

Comment: `sim = table[1];` takes 3 seconds? o.O

Comment: Can you provide some more code around the loop?
Are you sure that table[1] really takes 3 seconds? It's just an index into an in-memory list which should be very fast.

Comment: @Hogan - but they are evaluated :) `FirstOrDefault()`. But still strange times

Comment: I think you will need to provide a complete compilable repro.

Comment: @GiladGreen -- well the `.Find()` one should be lazy :)

Comment: since you are only interested in the first occurrence of the symbol did you try to change  List<symbol> to a dictionary where ,c is the key ?

Comment: @Hogan No, `Find` is a non-lazy method on `List<T>`.  Only something that returns `IEnumerable` is likely to be lazy.

Comment: I update what takes soo long time. This is all program, but program change like 10sec because of this line.

Comment: @Hogan `FirstOrDefault` returns a value not an Enumerable, it's absolutely not lazy.

Comment: I take it back -- these are not Lazy

Comment: @NejcGalof - I've just tried on a list containing 1000000 and each row out of these rows as less than 1ms... Pleas show the code populating the list and different queries around it

Comment: If you _always_ search by `c` the the fastest structure would be a `Dictionary<byte, symbol>`, or a `Lookup<byte, symbol>` if there are duplicates.  It takes more time to set up the structure but searches are O(1) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is not designed for efficient searching. If speed is important then you need a better data structure.

If you need to find all symbol with byte value c = x then I would have a dictionary of lists of symbols.

```
var symbols = new Dictionary<byte, List<Symbol>>();
```

When you add a symbol you should lookup the list and if not found create a new one

Comment: Yes this structure work much faster. My program now work 3 sec. Thank you.